# Selectable Elements outside of container with overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

first post...

So the issue is with two child elements being selectable outside of their parent container.

I have a container DIV with "overflow:hidden". Inside this container is a fixed image element, which I'm using to create a frosted glass overlay. So something like this:

```
<div id="container1" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index:1;">
  content, which is either the unblurred image, or a textarea, depending
</div>
<div id="container2" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height: 50px; z-index:3; overflow: hidden">
  <img id="frostedIMGcopy" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index:2; filter:blur(8px);"/>
  <div id="selectableMenuElement">Menu Option</div>
</div>
```

where "container2" has an opacity:0.5 background and the img is blurred. That looks how I want it too, no issues with getting that to work at all. I can adjust the height of container2 and it reveals the appropriate amount of blurred image, leaving it looking like the frosted glass overlay, no problems there either.

But when I want to access content on the lower "uncovered" 50px of container1, I am unable to get past the invisible portion of the what-should-be-inaccessible blurred img. It literally selects and drags the "hidden" portion of the picture "frostedIMGcopy" beyond the 50px threshold of container2.

There's more going on, but this is definitely the heart of the problem. My code actually has the identical problem with a frosted overlay of a textarea. In this scenario, selecting the uncovered textarea of container1 actually selects the text inside container2. Same problem, but this is why I need to sort this out.

The syntax in my actual code is fine, and otherwise everything works perfectly.

I can post more code if need be, but the problem really does boil down to these conceptual elements, and I'm completely lost as to what is happening here. Hopefully someone can shed some light on the situation so I'm not hung up on this detail forever.

The only thing I can figure is that the nested z-index is messing with things, but that still doesn't explain why the image in container2 is accessible outside its overflow bounds.

Thanks for any help with my "stack overflow" issue

*edited the code to reflect how it's being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because the attribute "position: fixed", the element in this case is relative to the browser Window/viewport, not to the parent element,

replace this:

```
<img id="frostedIMGcopy" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index:2; filter:blur(8px);"/>
```

with this:

```
<img id="frostedIMGcopy" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100px; height:100px; z-index:2; filter:blur(8px);"/>
```

the same for **id="selectableMenuElement"**

Comment: Shoot, that's exactly what I was hoping it wasn't. Now I have to go and build a bunch more containers and redefine where everything is sitting. It's so strange that you can still select the hidden portion beyond its parent container. I can't think of any instance where that's a useful trait.

Comment: it still belongs to its parent container in the DOM Structure, the only thing that has changed is the position (its offsets) and as soon as it is fixed, so its relative to the window not to the parent

Comment: Yeah that totally fixed it all. It was as easy as throwing some fixed containers around, and reposition all the elements inside as absolute. Made some of the background images in divs wonky, but easily fixed. Cheers

Comment: glad that i could help